# firefox plugin that records traffic

Tags: http, firefox, firebug, firefox-addon

Do you know of a firefox plugin that records the http traffic I generate while browsing?

I would like something like firebug's net tab but it should not "restart" every time I click a new link.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes - a debugger is definitely programming related...

Comment: I agree completely.  I haven't seen any closes for a while though so I'm hoping they saw the error of their ways :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647)

Excellent for debugging Ajax stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could also try the HttpWatch plugin for Firefox. It shows time charts like Firebug and groups requests by page as you click on different links:

[image: HttpWatch Page Grouping]
<sub>(source: [httpwatch.com](http://www.httpwatch.com/images/v5_pagegrouping.png))</sub>

There's a free and commercial edition. The free edition only displays detailed information for a limited number of well known sites (e.g. microsoft.com, google.com, etc).

You can find out more about HttpWatch on our web site:

http://www.httpwatch.com/

DISCLAIMER: This answer was posted by Simtec Limited the company behind HttpWatch

Comment: No reason for downvoting this answer. It's answering the question and there is a clear disclaimer.